# Calculate difference of data in respective weeks using week number

Tags: sql

My data is stored in Google Big QUery in a database. This is how my table looks like. Here Epid_ID is unique for each row and the count is calculated using this value.

```
 Admin_Level_2_district WeekNumber Epid_ID 
  Jhapa                  18        COV-NEP-PR1-SUN-20-00072
  Jhapa                  19        COV-NEP-PR1-SUN-20-00073
  Morang                 18        COV-NEP-PR1-SUN-20-00074
  Morang                 19        COV-NEP-PR1-SUN-20-00075
```

I want to find the difference in data in two weeks. This is my expected output.

```
 Admin_Level_2_district  count_Week_18  count_Week 19  Difference
  Jhapa                   50             60             10
  Morang                  60             50             -10
```

Following is the query I have tried.

```
  SELECT 
  Admin_Level_2_district,
  Week_number,
  count(Epid_ID) 
  FROM `interim-data.casedata.Interim EpiData` 
  GROUP BY 
  Admin_Level_2_district,
  Week_number
  HAVING Week_number = '18' 
  or Week_number = '19'
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want conditional aggregation here:

```
SELECT
    Admin_Level_2_district,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN WeekNumber = 18 THEN 1 END) AS count_Week_18,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN WeekNumber = 19 THEN 1 END) AS count_Week_19,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN WeekNumber = 19 THEN 1 END) -
        COUNT(CASE WHEN WeekNumber = 18 THEN 1 END) AS Difference
FROM `interim-data.casedata.Interim EpiData`
GROUP BY
    Admin_Level_2_district;
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use conditional aggregation.  In BigQuery, I would recommend `countif()`:

```
SELECT Admin_Level_2_district,
       COUNTIF(week_number = '18') as count_week_18,
       COUNTIF(week_number = '19') as count_week_19,
       COUNTIF(week_number = '19') - COUNTIF(week_number = '18') as diff
FROM `interim-data.casedata.Interim EpiData` 
WHERE Week_number IN ('18', '19')
GROUP BY  Admin_Level_2_district;
```

Note:  I would expect `week_number` to be a number, in which case you would not use single quotes.  However, your code treats that as a string, so I left that in.